# Changing background color Using Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to do the same thing as in the link, changing the color of the bag using Ember.js but not changing the image, just changing the color. I am kinda new in web programming so need help :)
http://www.timbuk2.com/tb2/customizer#!/product/10-custom-laptop-messenger-bag/size/4/customize

And here what I found, but can't make it work

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#view Ember.Button target="App.controller" action="blue"}}BLUE{{/view}}  
  {{#view Ember.Button target="App.controller" action="red"}}RED{{/view}} 

  {{#view App.View colorBinding="App.controller.color" attributeBindings="style"}}
    Color is {{App.controller.color}}
  {{/view}}

   <hr>
    <div {{bindAttr style="App.controller.style"}}>And another way...</div>
</script>






App = Ember.Application.create();
/**************************
* Models
**************************/


/**************************
* Views
**************************/
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
    style: function() {
      return "background-color:" + this.get('color');
    }.property('color').cacheable()
});

/**************************
* Controllers
**************************/
App.set('controller', Ember.Object.create({
  color: "transparent",

  red: function() {
    this.set('color', 'red');
  },

  blue: function() {
    this.set('color', 'blue');        
  },

  style: function() {
   return "background-color:" + this.get('color');
  }.property('color').cacheable()
}));
/**************************
* App Logic
**************************/
red (function() {
    console.log('blah'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are doing it so complicate, but this can be achieved in a very simple way:

### application template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="row">
    <button {{action 'changeColor' '428bca'}} class="btn btn-primary">Blue</button>
    <button {{action 'changeColor' 'f0ad4e'}} class="btn btn-warning">Orange</button>
    <button {{action 'changeColor' '5cb85c'}} class="btn btn-success">Green</button>
    <button {{action 'randomColor'}} class="btn btn-default">Random</button>
    <button {{action 'changeColor' 'ffffff'}} class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row box" {{bind-attr style=style}}></div>
</script>
```

### ApplicationController

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  color: 'ffffff',
  style: function() {
    return 'background-color:%@%@'.fmt('#', this.get('color'));
  }.property('color'),

  actions: {
    changeColor: function(color) {
      this.set('color', color);
    },
    // method added just for fun :)
    randomColor: function() {
      var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
      this.set('color', color);
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, what we are doing here is simple, this is the div which background color we are going to change `<div class="row box" {{bind-attr style=style}}></div>`. As you can see it has the `{{bind-attr}}` helper bound to the `style` attribute of the div. So when a button is clicked the `ApplicationController` will set the new color on the `ApplicationController` color property from which the `style` computed property depends on, this will make the computed property revaluate whenever the `color` property changes, by reevaluating the binding kicks in and will set your div's background color style.

Working [demo](http://jsbin.com/oGOwoXA/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep this help a lot too, both solutions are what I was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code looks very old. Try this:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <button {{action "blue"}}>Blue</button>
   <button {{action "red"}}>Red</button> 

    Color is {{color}}

   <hr>
   <div {{bindAttr style="style"}}>And another way...</div>
</script>
```

Javascript:
    window.App = Ember.Application.create({});

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("index", {path: "/"});
});


App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  color: "transparent",

  actions:{
    red: function() {
      this.set('color', 'red');
      console.log('color is red');
    },

    blue: function() {
      this.set('color', 'blue'); 
      console.log('color is blue');
    }

  },

  style: function() {
     return "background-color:" + this.get('color');
  }.property('color').cacheable()


});
```

JSBIN with this code: http://jsbin.com/IXokUQa/18/edit